# What frequency should be used for air-to-ground communication other than airport ground operation?

Tags: faa-regulations, radio-communications, visual-flight-rules

On a VFR flight, what frequency should be used to talk to somebody on the ground in USA?

In another word, if I am overflying my house and I would like to talk to the people on the ground, what frequency should I be using? Is it even legal to do something like this?

Comment: 850/900/1,800/1,900 MHz?   :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Radio frequencies in the USA are assigned by the [FCC](https://www.fcc.gov/), not the FAA. There's no 'private' air-to-ground frequency mentioned in the AIM but [section 4-1-11](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf) does say that the FCC has assigned 122.900 as a MULTICOM frequency for:

> Activities of a temporary, seasonal, emergency nature or search and
>   rescue, as well as, airports with no tower, FSS, or UNICOM

Arguably your fly-by is "temporary activity", however the definition of MULTICOM is:

> A mobile service not open to public correspondence used to provide
>   communications essential to  conduct the activities being performed by
>   or directed from private aircraft

So if your fly-by is "essential" (and safe!) then I guess you could use 122.9. There are [procedures](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/airshow/media/Air_Show_Freq_Request_Guidance.pdf) for requesting temporary air-to-ground frequencies for air shows, but that's obviously a special case.

As for legality, it seems that [you need an FCC license](http://wireless.fcc.gov/services/index.htm?job=operations&id=aircraft_stations) to use an aviation handheld radio on the ground:

> You may only use your hand-held aircraft VHF radio in your aircraft
>   under the terms of your aircraft license. You are required to have a
>   separate Ground Station license to operate your radio on the ground.

But because this is more about FCC regulations than FAA ones, I suggest that you ask on [ham.SE](https://ham.stackexchange.com/); they'll probably know a lot more about how it all works.

Answer (score -1):

Some people use "fingers" 123.45 for non-standard radio communications. I don't think it conflicts with any existing radio stations and its legality is in in doubt. Sometimes you will hear on a busy frequency "BOB! FINGERS" which is never acknowledge either by the intended recipient or by ATC, but it means t come up on 123.45

Comment: FYI the FCC has designated 123.450 MHz for flight test stations: `The use of flight test stations is restricted to the transmission of necessary information or instructions relating directly to tests of aircraft or components thereof.`

Comment: Probably why people use it!